# Forcing a process to background from bash script

Tags: ubuntu, bash-scripting, ubuntu-14.04, nohup

I'm trying to crfeate a bash script that - amongst other things starts sunwait:

```
/root/bin/sunwait sun up -0:00:00 54.453158N 11.013071E; mycommand &
```

Sunwait is a binary that will wait for astronomical events to happen before executing a given command.
I used the ampersand at the end to send it to the background so my script can continue to do other things but this does not work and i don't know why.

Executing the command directly on the shell will also not send sunwait to the background. I tried nohup too with no success.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 Server LTS. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sunwait is a binary that will wait for astronomical events to happen before executing a given command.

After examining your syntax I guess that this interpretation is wrong. In your example `sunwait` executes nothing, in fact there is no command given to it. I am not familiar with `sunwait`, but quick research revealed to me that it just waits for astronomical event and then finishes.

In your case it goes like this:

- The shell reads the line, encounters semicolon `;` and executes everything to that point -- that is the `sunwait` with its command line options.
- The shell waits for `sunwait` to finish.
- Eventually `sunwait` finishes, so the shell proceeds to `mycommand` and executes it in background because of ampersand `&`.

So, direct answer to your question is most common: it is not "working" (not doing what you want) because it is working (doing what you command).

Fix:

1. Either
   `{ /root/bin/sunwait sun up -0:00:00 54.453158N 11.013071E; mycommand; } &`
2. or
   `/root/bin/sunwait sun up -0:00:00 54.453158N 11.013071E && mycommand &`

In the first line the two commands inside `{}` appear to `&` as if it was single command, so everything goes to the background. Simple and often good enough. The second case is slightly different: `mycommand` will run if and only if `sunwait` finishes without error (unless `sunwait` is poorly coded). It is the behavior you expected in the first place, isn't it?. Personally I find the second fix more elegant. Imagine you made a mistake typing `mycommand` and realized after a while that it is a ticking bomb. Killing `sunwait` will trigger the bomb in 1st scenario, defuse it in 2nd.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation and for discussing the possible fixes!! I feel kind of stupid now and && is working like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Your line has two commands, separated by a semicolon (`;`). You need to either send both commands into the background:

```
/root/bin/sunwait sun up -0:00:00 54.453158N 11.013071E & mycommand &
```

Or, if you want the commands to run one after the other, run them both in a subshell and background that:

```
( /root/bin/sunwait sun up -0:00:00 54.453158N 11.013071E; mycommand ) &
```

I believe the latter example is what you're trying to achieve as the first one will start both commands right now and background them.